# ACF Date picker remove past dates from front end

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have job adds posted with Advanced Custom Fields which use the date picker field for the end date for the job add.

```
    <?php if (have_rows('jobs', 'option')): ?>
        <?php $now = time(); ?>
        <div id="jobs">
            <div class="jobs-title">
                <h2><?php the_field('active', 'option'); ?></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="jobs">
                <div class="inner-jobs flexing">
                    <?php $today = strtotime("now");
                    while (have_rows('jobs', 'option')): the_row();
                        $date_one_timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/y", get_sub_field('job-deadline', 'option'))->getTimestamp();
                        if ($date_one_timestamp > $today) { ?>
                            <div class="flex job flexing">
                                <div class="flex-small">
                                    <div class="bubble flex">
                                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('job-img', 'option'); ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-cont">
                                    <div class="job-title"><h4><?php the_sub_field('job-title', 'option'); ?></h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>Lõpptähtaeg: <?php echo date("y/m/d", $date_one_timestamp); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php the_sub_field('job-url', 'option'); ?>" target="_blank">
                                        <button><?php the_sub_field('job-button', 'option'); ?><span
                                                    class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span></button>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div><!-- job -->
                        <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div><!-- inner -->
            </div><!-- .jobs -->
        </div><!-- #jobs -->
    <?php endif; ?>
```

What i'm trying to achieve is not outputting the job adds which have an earlier date than today meaning they are not active anymore. So far I've achieved the above but this is giving out an error as follows:

> Fatal error
> : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean in /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/wp-content/themes/mtg/footer.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/wp-includes/template.php(688): require_once() #1 /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/wp-includes/template.php(647): load_template('/data01/virt648...', true) #2 /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/wp-includes/general-template.php(76): locate_template(Array, true) #3 /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/wp-content/themes/mtg/template-home.php(162): get_footer() #4 /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/wp-includes/template-loader.php(74): include('/data01/virt648...') #5 /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('/data01/virt648...') #6 /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/index.php(17): require('/data01/virt648. in
> /data01/virt64863/domeenid/www.xn--t-1gaa.viasat.ee/htdocs/wp-content/themes/mtg/footer.php
> on line
> 16

Any suggestions what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error parsing the date in this line:

```
$date_one_timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/y", get_sub_field('job-deadline', 'option'))
```

Have you looked into what this call is returning:

```
get_sub_field('job-deadline', 'option')
```

The function `createFromFormat` returns false if there is an error (see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php )

This explains your error message of trying to call `getTimestamp()` on a boolean!